# Where Do I Place Data Generation Scripts in VS2010 Database Project?

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010

I am working on a database project within VS2010.  I have created a few INSERT INTO scripts so I can populate the database with data which I can then test against.  However, I am unsure of where to put these scripts so that they are automatically run on deployment.  (For example, if I put items under the Schemas/Tables folder of the VS2010 DB Project, that is automatically run.  I want the same effect for population of data.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "Post-deployment scripts" folder?

Not exactly sure about the location in VS2010, but in 2008 it's a folder created by default in a database project.

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't know that those scripts were run automatically.